How do I retrieve a list of Facebook Business Pages?
I am trying to retrieve a list of all pages (business and non-business) that the account has. However, only non-business pages are currently being returned.
First I allow the user to login. He/she gets a Facebook Login popup, where he/she can select the pages.
Then I generate a long-lived token, like so:
const response = await axios.get(
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/oauth/access_token",
  {
    params: {
      grant_type: "fb_exchange_token",
      client_id: process.env.FB_APP_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.FB_APP_SECRET,
      fb_exchange_token: fbAccessToken,
    },
  }
);

I get a token just fine. I return the token and the client makes an api call to retrieve the pages:
const handleFacebookCallback = async (response: any) => {
  if (!response?.id) {
    return;
  }
  setLoading(true);
  const { data } = await api.post("/api/integrations/facebook/user", {
    userId: user._id,
    fbAccessToken: response.accessToken,
    fbUserId: response.id,
  });
  const url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/${response.id}/accounts?access_token=${data.longLivedToken}`;

  const fbResponse = await fetch(url);
  const fbData = await fbResponse.json();
  setResponseFbPages(fbData.data);
  setLoading(false);
};

Now, I have 3 pages - 2 are business and 1 non-business. Only the non-business pages are getting returned.
I tried to query the /accounts endpoint, and I am expecting to get a full list of pages returned.
